# Issue with logback configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I'm new to logBack in my Java Springboot application. I'm trying to push logs to database, using the following config.
But when I run the application, I keep getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error
> detected: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:16 - no
> applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath is
> [[Configuration][Appenders]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}</driverClass>
            <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
            <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
            <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your logback version?

Comment: Hi @seenukarthi, the version is 1.2.3. Thank you!